# Angular2: Email Confirmation in Account Registration

Tags: angular, email, ionic2

Good day, I am currently developing an e-commerce mobile app using Ionic 2 and I want to implement email confirmation(send verification code via email) in signing up new user account. Is there any way or tutorial I can use or based upon to implement email confirmation using Angular 2? Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a request from your front-end (Angular2) to your back-end (I recommend NodeJS for that), which will reach your mail server and send the mail.

Have a look at this post showing a good example : [Sending Email from Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192772/sending-email-from-angular-2)

Comment: thank you sir, does it automatically generate a verification code?

Comment: I believe not, your mail server will require some configuration I believe