# Firebase database validation connection to other databases and/or storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Could I have server side code on firebase database that references other databases or storages that I created? Like for example, have url of image in firebase storage be verified to exist when writing the url to database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I run server-side code in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653378/how-would-i-run-server-side-code-in-firebase)

Comment: Since the question Maxime linked was written, Firebase has released [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which might be used as the location that runs the validation code.